# Como direcionar una libreria bootstrap a un DIV de html

Tags: html, css

aca un ejemplo pequeño de un html, lo que pasas es que tengo un pagina la cual presenta su propio diseño(styles.css), y yo estoy implementando un diseño para un multiselect, lo cual requiere de bootstrap-multiselect.css y bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css .... entonces cuando añado este codigo de html se distorciona el diseño de lo que estoy añadiendo, pero estaba pensando implelemntan un DIV en el multiselect con un ID llamado "dibujo", y lo que deseo es que esas librerias de bootstrap que presento solo afecten a ese DIV

```
<br/><br/>
<label>DNI</label>
<input type="text" id="dni"> 

<div id="dibujo">
</br></br>
<select  id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
 <option value="2g">2G</option> 
  <option value="3g">3G</option> 
 <option value="4g">4G</option> 
 <option value="tdd">TDD</option>
  </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#tecnologia').multiselect({

    buttonText: function(options, select){
      console.log(select[0].length);
      if (options.length===0) {
        return 'sin Seleccion';
      }
      if (options.length===select[0].length) {
        return 'todos ('+select[0].length+')';
      }
      else if(options.length>=1){
        return options.length+' seleccionados';
      }else{

        var labels=[];
        console.log(options);
        options.each(function(){
          labels.push($(this).val());
        });
        return labels.join(', ')+'';
      }

    }
  });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es un codigo del bootstrap... como se ve es un codigo muy extenso
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es heredar plantillas

Comment: <?php include('plantilla.php'); ?> donde plantilla.php tiene toda la libreria css y js que ncesitas y la incluse en donde deseas en ese caso en un div

Comment: un ejemplo mas claro aqui http://www.falconmasters.com/web-design/como-hacer-plantilla-php/

Comment: pero son librerias ya descargadas, osea que las tengo en una carpeta

Comment: una es css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css y el otro es css/bootstrap-multiselect.css ... como se ve los dos estan en un carpeta llamada "css" y son fundamental para que se muestre el diseño del multiselect

Comment: por eso tienes que incluir tus librerias ya descargadas en tu plantilla.php luego mandas a llamar en el div mediante el header como te comente anteriormente

Comment: creo que no me estoy dejando entender, voy a subir mi codigo como pantallazo para que se vea mejor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76800/discussion-between-kevin-callupe-santillan-and-tegito123).